# setting the properties in a cq5 component

Tags: javascript, jsp, aem

I have created a custom component in cq5. I'd like to know that is there any way of setting the component properties in javaScript/jsp rather than setting it through edit design window.There is a getter method for getting the component properties in jsp, But i want to know about the setter methods.

Comment: It's possible to do both. You can resolve the resource in the JSP and set the property using Java code. As for JavaScript, when you use the dialog, the browser issues an HTTP request to CQ to save the data. You can send a similar request from your own JavaScript code.

Comment: The latter method you specified seems to match my requirement.Can you please give me any pointers on how to do that or elaborate more on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a setProperty to a Node ? yes you can set the property of a jcr Node here is the documentation http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html see the setProperty methods. So to access through jsp you need to do

```
<% 
Node resourceNode = resourceResolver.resolve("path to the node having property").adaptTo(Node.class);
 resourceNode.setProperty(Name, Value);
%>
```

Make sure that you import required packages. Hope this helps.